# Alamofire carthage update not working for Xcode 12 Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage, xcode12

I have added Cartfile for Alamofire.
Cartfile contains: github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 5.2

After I run: **carthage update --platform iOS**

giving:
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 1:
/usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create /Users/****/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A7209/Alamofire/5.2.2/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire\ iOS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire /Users/****/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A7209/Alamofire/5.2.2/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire -output /Users/****/Desktop/untitled/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log...

The build framework file is generated and I can drag that to Project embedded Framework, but when I am trying to run the project its not running in Simulator. I can run in device, but not simulator.

[image]

What can I do to solve this, One point is Alamofire is working in Simulator with cocoapod, but problem is occurring with carthage.
Thank you.

**My carthage version: 0.36.0**

**Xcode: 12.0**

**Alamofire: "5.2.2"**

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3313 Seems to be a Carthage issue. It's stated in big in there release note: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases

Comment: oh, I see. really problematic then, just was planning to incorporate carthage in my project files instead of pods.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Carthage (0.36.0) not working with Xcode 12.0

check and wait a new version for Carthage with fix :
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases

or you can use this workaround :
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md